# How to draw a scheduling scheme?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I would like to draw an arbitration scheduling scheme. I tried to draw one with xfig, but the result is... not so nice ;-):

[image]

Does anyone know a good way to draw this in LaTeX? The result don't have to be exactly like my example. I also tried the `pgfgantt` package, but don't know how to change the right border from the bar of "Master 3"...

```
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid]{15}
\ganttbar{Master 1}{7}{9} \\
\ganttbar{Master 2}{2}{4} \\
\ganttbar{Master 3}{5}{6} \ganttbar{}{10}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Master 4}{11}{13}
\end{ganttchart}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Could the [`tikz-timing` -package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing) be of help here?

Comment: How about [`pgfgantt`](http://ctan.cdpa.nsysu.edu.tw/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf), [`pst-gantt`](http://shadow.ind.ntou.edu.tw/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-gantt/pst-gantt-doc.pdf)?

Comment: I tried `pgfgant` already (see the code), but don't know how to change the right border from the Master 3 task in my example. I want to clearly show that this task would be interrupted...

Answer (score 6):

With a few adjustments (the `path picture bounding box` is clipped against the path picture), a few empirical values (the `.6\pgflinewidth` probably won’t work for other line widths) and without vertical correction of the bar (the same reason as before), one can achieve the following.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{Shift/.style 2 args={shift={(+#1.5\pgflinewidth,+#2.5\pgflinewidth)}}}
\newcommand*{\pgfkeysstylelet}[2]{\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\expandafter\endcsname\csname pgfk@#2/.@cmd\endcsname}
\ganttset{
    /tikz/broken/.style={
        decoration={
            name=zigzag,
            amplitude=+1pt,
            segment length=+2pt}},
    broken right/.code={
        \pgfkeysstylelet{/pgfgantt/bar backup}{/pgfgantt/bar}
        \pgfkeysalso{
            /pgfgantt/bar left shift=-.5\pgflinewidth/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
            /pgfgantt/bar right shift=(.5\pgflinewidth+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude)/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
            /pgfgantt/bar/.append style={
                draw=none,
                path picture={
                    \draw[/pgfgantt/bar backup, broken] ([Shift=+-] path picture bounding box.north west) |-
                                                        ([Shift=-+, xshift=-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.south east)
                                           decorate {-- ([Shift=--, xshift=-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.north east)}
                                                     -- cycle;}}}},
    broken left/.code={
        \pgfkeysstylelet{/pgfgantt/bar backup}{/pgfgantt/bar}
        \pgfkeysalso{
            /pgfgantt/bar right shift=.5\pgflinewidth/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
            /pgfgantt/bar left shift=(-.5\pgflinewidth-.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude)/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
            /pgfgantt/bar/.append style={
                draw=none,
                path picture={
                    \draw[/pgfgantt/bar backup, broken] ([Shift=--] path picture bounding box.north east) |-
                                                        ([Shift=++, xshift=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.south west)
                                           decorate {-- ([Shift=+-, xshift=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.north west)}
                                                     -- cycle;}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid]{15}
\ganttbar{Master 1}{7}{9} \\
\ganttbar{Master 2}{2}{4} \\
\ganttbar[broken right]{Master 3}{5}{6} \ganttbar[broken left]{}{10}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Master 4}{11}{13}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an adaptation of Qrrbrbirlbel's code so that you can make both the left and the right side of the ganttbar jagged:

```
\newcommand*{\pgfkeysstylelet}[2]{\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\expandafter\endcsname\csname pgfk@#2/.@cmd\endcsname}
\ganttset{
    /tikz/broken/.style={
      decoration={
        name=zigzag,
        amplitude=+1pt,
        segment length=+2pt}},
    broken right/.code={
        \pgfkeysstylelet{/pgfgantt/bar backup}{/pgfgantt/bar}
        \pgfkeysalso{
            /pgfgantt/bar left shift=-.5\pgflinewidth/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
            /pgfgantt/bar right shift=(.5\pgflinewidth+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude)/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
            /pgfgantt/bar/.append style={
                draw=none,
                path picture={
                  \draw[/pgfgantt/bar backup, broken]
                  ([Shift=+-] path picture bounding box.north west) |-
                  ([Shift=-+, xshift=-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.south east)
                  decorate {-- ([Shift=--, xshift=-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.north east)}
                  -- cycle;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    broken left/.code={
        \pgfkeysstylelet{/pgfgantt/bar backup}{/pgfgantt/bar}
        \pgfkeysalso{
            /pgfgantt/bar right shift=.5\pgflinewidth/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
            /pgfgantt/bar left shift=(-.5\pgflinewidth-.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude)/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
            /pgfgantt/bar/.append style={
                draw=none,
                path picture={
                  \draw[/pgfgantt/bar backup, broken]
                  ([Shift=--] path picture bounding box.north east) |-
                  ([Shift=++, xshift=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.south west)
                  decorate {-- ([Shift=+-, xshift=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.north west)}
                  -- cycle;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    broken both/.code={
        \pgfkeysstylelet{/pgfgantt/bar backup}{/pgfgantt/bar}
        \pgfkeysalso{
          /pgfgantt/bar left shift=(-.5\pgflinewidth-.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude)/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
          /pgfgantt/bar right shift=(.5\pgflinewidth+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude)/\ganttvalueof{x unit},
            /pgfgantt/bar/.append style={
                draw=none,
                path picture={
                  \draw[/pgfgantt/bar backup, broken]
                  ([Shift=-+, xshift=-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.south east)
                  decorate {-- ([Shift=--, xshift=-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.north east)};
                  \draw[/pgfgantt/bar backup, broken]
                  ([Shift=++, xshift=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.south west)
                  decorate {-- ([Shift=+-, xshift=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.north west)};
                  \draw[/pgfgantt/bar backup, broken]
                  ([Shift=++, xshift=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.south west) --
                  ([Shift=-+, xshift=-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.south east);
                  \draw[/pgfgantt/bar backup, broken]
                  ([Shift=--, xshift=-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.north east) --
                  ([Shift=+-, xshift=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+.6\pgflinewidth] path picture bounding box.north west);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now you can write e.g: `\ganttbar[broken both]{}{16}{18}`. Perhaps this is useful to someone.

I noticed that this doesn't really work if you want to use fill colors. If someone can fix that I'd be very happy!