# How to draw process scheduling schemes?

Tags: technical-drawing

I was wondering whether it was possible to draw something like the following in Latex. If so what kind of package do I need to use?

An example: [image: Scheduled processes]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. `tikz` is one possibility. `pstricks` and friends is probably another. What have you tried?

Comment: I don't use it, but there is a package `pgf-umlsd` that does some sort of process diagrams.  Maybe it can do these...

Comment: I tried using Tikz, but I couldn't find a good example to fix the node after each other :( and space them properly.

Comment: The problem is more the spacing :(, I don't know how to do that yet in Tikz, maybe there is a bit friendlier package. I haven't used pgf-umlsd, but I will look into it.

Comment: I suggest using pgfgantt as demonstrated here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110742/how-to-draw-a-scheduling-scheme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with `TiKZ` and something like

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=-1mm, font=\sffamily, >=Latex,
    burst/.style 2 args={draw,rounded corners,anchor=north west, minimum width=1cm, 
                         minimum height=#2mm, name=n#1, node contents=$n_{#1}$, inner sep=0pt}]

\draw (0,0) -- (0,90);
\foreach \i in {0,10,20,...,90}
    \draw (0,\i) node[left] {\i}--++(0:.3);

\foreach \i [count=\p] in {1,3,5}
{
\draw[dashed] (\i,0) rectangle ++(1,90);
\node[above,xshift=0.5cm] at (\i,0) {P\p};
}

\path (1,28) node[burst={2}{12}];
\path (1,57) node[burst={8}{7}];

\foreach \i/\j/\k in {4/8/18, 6/18/26,9/12/55,10/6/74}
    \path (3,\k) node[burst={\i}{\j}];

\foreach \i/\j/\k in {1/10/0, 3/20/10,5/8/30,7/12/38}
    \path (5,\k) node[burst={\i}{\j}];

\draw[->] (n1.south west) to[out=190,in=60] (n2.north east);
\draw[->] (n1.south west) -- (n4.north east);
\draw[->] (n1.south west) -- (n6.north east);
\draw[->] (n7.south west) -- (n10.north east);
\draw[->] (n4.south west) -- (n8.north east);
\draw[->] (n6.south west) -- (n8.north east);
\draw[->] (n2.south east) -- (n9.north west);
\draw[->] (n8.south east) -- (n10.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A small additional question, in what kind of IDE did you code this? Is there something like a liveview (so I can see what I'm drawing?). Thank you for your clear code!

Comment: @Snowflake I just use TeXworks. Long time ago I tested TikZedit but never used it. Some more tools: [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24235/1952), [Need recommendations for a drawing tool in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9775/1952), [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26972/1952) or [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205/1952)